# increase speed/velocity, cocos2D

Tags: performance, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, acceleration

I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12

but at the last part, it shows how we can reduce speed by applying damping on a body

```
            if (speed > maxSpeed) {
                b->SetLinearDamping(0.5);
            }
```

Where "b" is a body on the world object.

I'm looking for a way to increase the speed by setting linear acceleration (maybe by applying a force ? I don't really know how to do this)

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to set the value to > 1, but less than some other number, perhaps 1.5?

Comment: I just tried, but as I guessed, it increases the damping, so lowers the velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found a way by applying a force too

```
b2Vec2 velocity = b->GetLinearVelocity();
if (speed <minSpeed) {
   b->ApplyForceToCenter(velocity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
b2Vec2 force;
force.Set(10.0f, 0.0f);

b->ApplyForce(force, b->GetWorldCenter());
```

This will set a force on your body on the positive x direction giving you a constant acceleration for you body.